# Questions on parity transformation

Tags: momentum, coordinate-systems, definition, parity

Is a parity transformation
$$(,,) → (−,,)$$

or

$$(,,) → (−,−,−)$$

Which coordinates cancel out momentum?

$(,,)$ (clockwise directions) and $(−,,)$ (counterclockwise directions)

or

$(,,)$ and $(−,-,-)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)

Comment: *Which one equals zero?* Zero??

Comment: Redarding momentum

Comment: Can you be more specific about " equal to zero"?

Comment: Depends on who you ask, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/382591/why-is-it-claimed-that-the-spin-of-60-textco-is-reversed-under-parity/382592#382592).

Comment: When you flip the coordinates, the directions and positions are reversed. For the second question, I was asking do clockwise and counterclockwise directions cancel out or do all directions have to be reversed to cancel out momentum?

Comment: Your two transformations are related by twice a right angle rotation around the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

> Is a parity transformation
> $(x,y,z)→(−x,y,z)$ or $(x,y,z)→(−x,−y,−z)$

A [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)) transformation (also called parity inversion) is the flip in the sign of one spatial coordinate. In three dimensions, it can also refer to the simultaneous flip in the sign of all three spatial coordinates (a point reflection)
or
$$\mathbf{P}:\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
-x \\
-y \\
-z
\end{pmatrix}$$

A spatial inversion (or parity transformations) is simple a map $\vec{x}\rightarrow -\vec{x}$. Mathematically such a transformation are characterized by the conditons $$\mathrm{det} O=-1    \mathrm{  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ and \ \\ \ \ \ } O^TO=1. $$

---

For the other question, you should be more specific to what you want to ask.

Comment: Why do you assert that “the second one is correct” after quoting Wikipedia that there are two different definitions of a parity transformation in 3D? Neither is “correct” or “incorrect”.

Comment: I added a more general definition.